# Reload images with different size in Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I wrote some jquery/php to reload images in my wordpress theme on the window resize. It loads random code and then crashes. Any ideas are welcome.
Thank you.

PHP

```
function head_scripts() {
    if ( !is_admin() ) {
        wp_localize_script( 'init', 'theme_info', array( 'ajax' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
    }
} add_action('init', 'head_scripts');


function image_echo($size, $i_ID) {
    $image_attr = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($i_ID), $size);

    ?><img itemprop="image" class="ajax-resize" attachment-id="<?php echo get_post_thumbnail_id ($i_ID) ?>" src="<?php echo $image_attr[0]; ?>" width="<?php echo $image_attr[1]; ?>" height="<?php echo $image_attr[2]; ?>" alt="<?php echo get_the_title($i_ID); ?>"/><?php
}


function resize_ajax_image() {
    if(isset($_POST['image_size'])) {
        $image_size = $_POST['image_size'];
    }

    if(isset($_POST['attachment_id'])) {
        $attachment_id = $_POST['attachment_id'];
    }

    image_echo($image_size, $attachment_id);
    die();

} add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_resize_ajax_image', 'resize_ajax_image' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_resize_ajax_image', 'resize_ajax_image' );
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function find_ajax_images(imageSize) {
        $('.ajax-resize').each(function(){
            var attachmentID = parseInt($(this).attr('attachment-id'));
            $.ajax(
                theme_info.ajax,{
                    type: 'POST',
                    cache: false,
                    data: {
                        action: 'resize_ajax_image',
                        image_size: imageSize,
                        attachment_id: attachmentID
                    },
                    success: function(resizeImage){
                        $(this).html(resizeImage);
                    }
                });
        });
    }


    function fixImages() {
        var winHeight = $(window).height();
        var winWidth = $(window).width();

        if (winWidth < 800) {
            //$('body').css('background-color','red');
            find_ajax_images('mobile');

        } else if (winWidth < 1024) {
            //$('body').css('background-color','yellow');
            find_ajax_images('small_1024');

        } else if (winWidth < 1280) {
            //$('body').css('background-color','green');
            find_ajax_images('medium_1280');

        } else if (winWidth < 1440) {
            //$('body').css('background-color','white');
            find_ajax_images('medium_1440');

        } else if (winWidth < 1680) {
            //$('body').css('background-color','magenta');
            find_ajax_images('large_1680');

        } else { // > 1680
            //$('body').css('background-color','brown');
            find_ajax_images('large_1920');

        } //nested if
    }

    $(window).bind('resize', function () { 
        fixImages();
    });

});
```

Comment: Try to refrain from posting a block of coding and saying - fix it. How about where does it crash? Client side, server side, browser crash? If in php can you turn on error reporting and let us know what happens? If in javascript at what line does it crash? etc.

Comment: I suggest you not use ajax here, just change the src of images on resize to something like img.php?img.jpg&size=large1024;

Comment: and that cople of elseif.... i personaly hate that style

Comment: Apparently it reloads modernizr and injects all the classes again. Then it loads my .less styles again like a hundred times. Then the browser page crashes.

Comment: @eicto could you be a little more graphical about changing the src of the images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@eicto 's solution was the optimal, but it doesn't really integrates with the way Wordpress works with images (media library). So yes, in the end I did some ajax with jQuery.

First, [localize your ajax](http://www.garyc40.com/2010/03/5-tips-for-using-ajax-in-wordpress/#js-global), then:

```
// your image sizes
if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) { 
    add_image_size( 'mobile', 300, 485 );
    add_image_size( 'small_960', 500, 800 );
    add_image_size( 'medium_1024', 540, 870 );
    add_image_size( 'medium_1280', 670, 1100 );
    add_image_size( 'large_1440', 760, 1230 );
    add_image_size( 'large_1680', 880, 1420 );
}

// use this to load images inside your loop (with the proper adjustment)
function image_echo($size, $i_ID) {
    $image_attr = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id ($i_ID), $size);

    ?><img itemprop="image" id="image-atta-<?php echo get_post_thumbnail_id ($i_ID) ?>" class="ajax-resize" attachment-id="<?php echo get_post_thumbnail_id ($i_ID) ?>" src="<?php echo $image_attr[0]; ?>" width="<?php echo $image_attr[1]; ?>" height="<?php echo $image_attr[2]; ?>" alt="<?php echo get_the_title($i_ID); ?>" /><?php
}

// return the resized image
function resize_ajax_image() {

    if(isset($_POST['image_size']) && isset($_POST['attachment_id'])) {
        $image_size = $_POST['image_size'];
        $attachment_id = $_POST['attachment_id'];

        $i_attr = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment_id, $image_size);

        $response = json_encode(array(
            'url' => $i_attr[0],
            'width' => $i_attr[1],
            'height' => $i_attr[2],
        ));
        header("Content-Type: application/json");
        echo $response;

        exit;
    }

} add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_resize_ajax_image', 'resize_ajax_image' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_resize_ajax_image', 'resize_ajax_image' );
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function resize_images(size) {
        imageSize = size;
        images = $('img.ajax-resize'); //the image for all resizable images

        images.each(function(){
            var this_image = $(this);
            var attachmentID = this_image.attr('attachment-id');

            $(this).hide();

            $.ajax(
                theme_info.ajax,{
                    type: 'POST',
                    cache: false,
                    data: {
                        action: 'resize_ajax_image',
                        image_size: imageSize,
                        attachment_id: attachmentID
                    },
                    success: function(image){
                        //console.log(this);
                        this_image.attr({
                            src: image.url, //json object values returned by wordpress
                            height: image.height,
                            width: image.width
                        }).fadeIn(500);

                    },
                    error: function(e){
                        console.log(e);
                    }
                });
        });
    }

    var last_image;
    var last_size;

    function last_img_fn(keyword) { //do not double resize to the same size
        if (last_image != keyword) {
            last_image = keyword;
            resize_images(keyword);
            //console.log(keyword);
        }
    }

    function if_stops_resizing() { //delay 1 second between user starts resizing and when ends. if it corresponds, then resize
        last_size = $(window).height() * $(window).width();

        window.setTimeout(function() {
            current_size = $(window).height() * $(window).width();

            if (current_size == last_size) {
                fixImages();
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }, 1000);
    }

    function fixImages() { //this will depend on how many media queries you do in css or your specific needs
        var winHeight = $(window).height();
        var winWidth = $(window).width();

        if (winWidth < 800) {
            //$('body').css('background-color','red');
            last_img_fn('mobile');

        }
            if (winWidth < 1024) {
            //$('body').css('background-color','yellow');
            last_img_fn('small_960');

        }
            if (winWidth < 1280) {
            //$('body').css('background-color','green');
            last_img_fn('medium_1024');

        }
            if (winWidth < 1440) {
            //$('body').css('background-color','white');
            last_img_fn('medium_1280');

        }
            if (winWidth < 1680) {
            //$('body').css('background-color','magenta');
            last_img_fn('large_1440');

        }
            else { // > 1680
            //$('body').css('background-color','brown');
            last_img_fn('large_1680');

        }
    } fixImages(); //fix images on load (not quite sure if the best)


    $(window).bind('resize', function () {
        var winHeight = $(window).height();
        var winWidth = $(window).width();

        last_size = winHeight * winWidth;
        //console.log(last_size);

        if_stops_resizing(); //this triggers the whole sequence
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok here we go:

img_get.php:

```
<?php
if (is_file($_GET['img'].'_'.$_GET['size'].'.jpg')) {
   $myImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($_GET['img'].'_'.$_GET['size'].'.jpg');
} else  {$myImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($_GET['img'].'.jpg');
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
imagejpeg($myImage);
imagedestroy($myImage);
?>
```

html sample:

```
<img class="fixableimg" isrc="common">
```

js:

```
function img_size(Wwidth) {
    if (Wwidth < 800) {
        return("mobile");
    }
    if (Wwidth < 1024) {
        return ("small_1024");
    }
    if (Wwidth < 1280) {
        return ("small_1280");
    }
    //.....
    return ("large_1920");

}

    $(window).bind('resize', function() {
        $('.fixableimg').each(function() {
            var obj = $(this);
            var img = obj.attr('isrc');
            var Wwidth = $(window).height();
            obj.attr('src','img_get.php?img='+img+'&size='+img_size(Wwidth));
            });
    });
```

something like that

Comment: Much simpler and cleaner. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Still, Wordpress won't be as happy with it. I'll try to integrate it with the media uploader and see if it works.